# How to erase previously set one-time default value

Tags: django

In my django app, I had to set a one-time default value for one of the fields when I tried to migrate.
When I did this, however, I accidentally set a wrong value. Ever since then, the same error pops up when I try to migrate:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000'
```

This is despite the fact that I rectified the issue in my code - it seems like this issue is stuck forever. Anything I can do to fix this?

Traceback:

```
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 112, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 433, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 161, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 233, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 789, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 959, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 968, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000'
```

Comment: Can you share your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong default is probably still present in your migration file.

If you have not applied this migration yet, you can just delete it and recreate it with `python manage.py migrate`.